# How to instantiate a materializer for AkkaStreams when I have a reference to the typed actor system?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-typed

The code below does not compile, it says that ActorMaterializer is missing an implicit ActorRefFactory. How should I provide one?

```
val guardian: Behavior[Done] = Behaviors.setup(_ => {
  Behaviors.receiveMessage{
    case Done => Behaviors.stopped
  }
})
implicit val sys = ActorSystem(guardian, "sys")
implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Akka Streams at this point requires a "classic" (untyped) `ActorSystem` which can be implicitly converted into a materializer.

So if materializing a stream inside an Akka Typed `Behavior`, one would

```
implicit val materializer = context.classicActorContext.system
```

And if materializing a stream outside of an actor but where you have a typed `ActorSystem`:

```
implicit val materializer = typedActorSystem.classicSystem
```

As mentioned by @johanandren, one can also put the Typed `ActorSystem` in the implicit scope, which will allow the implicit conversion to `Materializer` to take effect.

```scala
implicit val system = context.system
```

Comment: Just to add some information: the implicit conversion is there: https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/Materializer$.html (it is called `matFromSystem`)

Answer (score 6):

Previous answers are halfways to the indended new API.

The typed `ActorSystem` can be implicitly transformed to provide the system materialiser as well, so just having it available as an implicit should be enough.

For example:

```
Behaviors.setup { ctx =>
 implicit val system = ctx.system

 Source(1 to 10).runForeach(println)

 ...
}
```

The inner working of this is an implicit conversion available from the `Materializer` companion object that extracts the system materializer of a `ClassicActorSystemProvider` into a `Materializer`. Both the typed and the classic `ActorSystem` implements `ClassicActorSystemProvider`.

Answer (score 4):

The Akka documentation for 2.6.x indicates that ActorMaterializer is deprectated: "Use the system wide materializer or Materializer.apply(actorContext) with stream attributes or configuration settings to change defaults."

Use this instead:

```
import akka.Done
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.Behavior
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.stream.Materializer


object Main {

  def main(Args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val guardian: Behavior[Done] = Behaviors.setup(_ => {
      Behaviors.receiveMessage{
        case Done => Behaviors.stopped
      }
    })

    val as = ActorSystem()
    val materializer = Materializer(as)
  }
}
```